# What other standards exist for Hardware QA?

Tags: test-management, standards, hardware

I have been tasked with considering standards that can be used for hardware testing and QA - the hardware in this case being, for example, DAQ (DAC/ADC) and timing systems for diagnostics in a physics research environment (hardware cards with 2 kinds of software driver layers and then user applications at the top).

The organization this is meant for has already adopted ISO/IEC 12207 for Software Processes and I am trying to understand how this co-exists with ISO/IEC 15288.

At the same time, there is a task of evaluating other possible standards that could be considered.

So, if you don't mind my asking this in a Software QA forum (I am assuming that some of you *also* wear hardware testing hats!), what other standards could you suggest for me to look at (instead of 15288)?

Comment: Before anyone closes as off-topic, I would love to hear whether @KevinM could look for an answer on such topic? What are relevant on-topic places/fora on the Web to ask this question?

Comment: I searched long and hard through all the Stack Exchange sites, but none were precisely appropriate. I took a chance coming to sqa as it was closest (and had some relevance to my other questions). This question has already received 1 down vote (but 2 up votes). I welcome other suggestions.

Comment: I would love to hear justification of the downvote, so that the question can be improved. Given your explanation, the downvote is not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

A national standards body sent me a list of standards.. buried in there are references to:

ISO/IEC 90003 "Software engineering - Guidelines for the application of ISO 9001:2000 to computer software"

and

ISO/IEC TR 90005 "Systems engineering - Guidelines for the application of ISO 9001 to system life cycle processes"

which, at the very least, implies that one can use good old [ISO 9001](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/management-standards/iso_9000.htm)!